# Craft beers and Microbreweries in Melbourne?

Tags: breweries, craft-beers, micropub, australia

There are several lists online for craft brews in Melbourne, Australia:

- https://foursquare.com/top-places/melbourne/best-places-craft-beer
- https://www.theurbanlist.com/melbourne/a-list/melbournes-best-craft-breweries
- https://concreteplayground.com/melbourne/food-drink/drink/the-ten-best-craft-beer-bars-and-pubs-in-melbourne/

Are there others that are not on any of these lists?

Are there any nearby the Melbourne Convention and Exhibition Centre ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the work yourself. [Google lists about 15 craft breweries](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US751&q=melbourne%20micro%20breweries&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=-37876314,144977068,10910&tbm=lcl&ved=0ahUKEwii4q2Wm-_bAhVgJDQIHbTPAkQQjGoIZg&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!2m1!1e16!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:!1m3!1d148035.92266011552!2d145.08454344999998!3d-37.86729595!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i325!2i282!4f13.1;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!2m1!1e16!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9) in downtown Melbourne. I would have to say that's probably the most up to date list

Comment: Cos I'm not local and maybe there's some places that a local would recommend and Google would miss out =)